# How do I create a hidden field in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC3. When I make a field with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowKey)
```

Then the value gets sent back to the controller which is what I need. However I don't want the field to be visible even though I want its value to be returned to the controller.

Is there a way I can make a field hidden with MVC3?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowKey)
```

see [What does Html.HiddenFor do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866716/what-does-html-hiddenfor-do) for an example

Answer (score 44):

If you want to keep `Html.EditorFor()`, you could always mark a particular property of your model as hidden:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput;

public class Model
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    // some property
}
```

Comment: I prefer your solution and updated it to include more details about the attribute. And although I don't use the strategy of just doing `Html.EditorForModel()` and prefer to be specific about what to include per property, I just use `Html.EditorFor`. I think if I started again though, I would use `Html.EditorForModel` and customise everything using the scaffolding and attributes.

Comment: Is there any fundamental difference between using these two approaches? Except the syntactic sugar perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RowKey, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style="display: none" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the hiddenfor helper, like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RowKey)
```