# How to pass a model to a View

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

`System.NullReferenceException` is thrown everytime I try to insert the data into a database. 
I try to pass a model to a controller action, but obviously I send a null.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Answer(int step = -1, int techniqueId = -1)
    {

        StepsAnswersViewModel model = new StepsAnswersViewModel
        {
            Step = db.Steps
                .Where(x => x.TechniqueId == techniqueId & x.Order == step)
                .Select(x => x)
                .First()
        };

        ViewBag.step = step;
        ViewBag.tId = techniqueId;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Answer(StepsAnswersViewModel model)
```

Answer.chtml:

```
@model BachelorProject.Models.StepsAnswersViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Answer";
 }

@Html.Partial("_Test", Model)
```

_Test.chtml:

```
@model BachelorProject.Models.StepsAnswersViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Answer";
 }

<h2>Answer</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Answer", "Home", 
             new { step = ViewBag.step + 1, echniqueId = 1 }, 
             FormMethod.Post))
{
  <label>@Model.Step.Text</label>
  @Model.Step.Id
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)
  <input type="submit" value="Next Step" />
}
```

When I click "Next Step", null is passed to the "Answer" action for a Post requests...

StepsAnswersViewModel:

```
public class StepsAnswersViewModel
{
    public Step Step { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `StepsAnswersViewModel` definition ?

Comment: `Step` has `Id` and `Text` fields ?

Comment: Try `.First().AsNoTracking()` you're probably hitting a property that's being lazy loaded and by the time the view goes to grab it the context has been disposed.

Comment: @BradChristie, what would be the Id if there is no corresponding form field ?
ShukhratRaimov, is model null after the post ?

Comment: @Ofiris: I'm referring to `@Model.Step.Text`-- either need to `Include("Step")` or disable lazy-loading.

Comment: @Ofiris Yes, and one more int field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your form fields with the following html helpers:

```
@html.LabelFor(model => model.Step.Text)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Step.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text)
```

Then set a breakpoint in the `Answer` Post action, check the `model` parameters contents.

Comment: You very welcome, I encourage you to read more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866716/what-does-html-hiddenfor-do
And a nice tutorial here: http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/