# how to send hidden field to controller via model binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, hidden-field, nouislider

Hope one kindly can help me, it may be  a simple question but frustrated me as there is no fix for it,

I want to pass value from a hidden field to controller via model binding,
no matter what approach I use, just passing the value from view to controller via model can work for me,

this is my slider range

```html
<label for="amount">دامنه قیمت:</label>
<div id="connect" class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background">

</div>
```

this is the hidden field,

```html
<input type="hidden" name="MinPrice" value="@Model.MinPrice" id="MinPrice" />
<input type="hidden" name="MaxPrice" value="@Model.MaxPrice" id="MaxPrice" />
```

```js
< script >
  var connectSlider = document.getElementById('connect');

noUiSlider.create(connectSlider, {
  start: [40000, 800000],
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 2000000
  }
}); < /script>
        <script>
            var connectBar = document.createElement('div'),
                connectBase = connectSlider.querySelector('.noUi-base');

            / / Give the bar a class
for styling and add it to the slider.
connectBar.className += 'connect';
connectBase.appendChild(connectBar);

connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle, a, b, handlePositions) {

  var offset = handlePositions[handle];

  // Right offset is 100% - left offset
  if (handle === 1) {
    offset = 100 - offset;
  }

  // Pick left for the first handle, right for the second.
  connectBar.style[handle ? 'right' : 'left'] = offset + '%';
}); < /script>
        

        <script>


            var valueInput = document.getElementById('MinPrice'),
                valueSpan = document.getElementById('MaxPrice');

            / / When the slider value changes, update the input and span
connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  if (handle) {
    valueInput.value = values[handle];
  } else {
    valueSpan.innerHTML = values[handle];
  }
});

// When the input changes, set the slider value
valueInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  connectSlider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
});


< /script>
```

this is my JS that fill the hidden field, these two fields are filled correctly, but dont send data to controller via model,

thank you all pal,

***Updated***

this is my model:

```
 public class SearchModel
{
    public string Devision { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Sport { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string ProductGroup { get; set; }
    public List<tblSiteItem> Result { get; set; }
    public List<tblSiteItem> Sales { get; set; }
    public List<string> Devisions { get; set; }
    public List<string> Genders { get; set; }
    public List<string> Brands { get; set; }
    public List<string> Sports { get; set; }
    public List<string> Sizes { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProductGroups { get; set; }
    public List<tblSiteCart> CartItems { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

As I said the value is filled correctly so I do not need code to make it corrected, Just not bind the hdnValue to the field in my model.
I mean MinPrice and MaxPrice.

***Edited***
I am not allowed to upload images sadly, If I were everything was pretty obvious to look at,
any way, I explain the detail:

1. when I change the slideBar, my JS fires and values change,
2. when I click the search button all the fields in my model is field except for these two field , I mean MinPrice and MaxPrice
3. result shows an empty page , again my Js keep fired then come back to the default values,

in the last try I changed the hidden field to type="text"
 
and saw that when I change the slidebar the value is in my text box but not binded to my view model when touch search button.

**I am sure there is something wrong with my viewmodel, but How I can understand what is incorrect :( please kindly look at my code**

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for get the value:

```js
var userRole = "";
userRole = $("#hdnVal").val();
alert(userRole);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hdnVal" value="@Model.MinPrice" />
```

Comment: in your example  u wrote <input type="hidden" id="hdnVal" value="YourValue" />  Your value I expect to be a Model.MinPrice, with that I  expect to see my model is filled with this data in the controller

Comment: **Try this:**
Instead of value="YourValue"  you can put value="@Model.MinPrice".

Comment: I tested this too but no success, please review the updated post, thanks for your time my friend

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this.**

**On .cshtml Page**

> `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>   <input type="hidden" id="hdnVal" value="@Model.MinPrice" />
>   <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />`

**Js**

```
var userRole = "";
userRole = $("#hdnVal").val();
alert(userRole);
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("userRole ", userRole);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/YourAction/",
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
          if (result.Message == "success") {
            alert("Success");
          }
        }
      });

    }
```

**C# Code**

```
public JsonResult YourAction()
{
string Role = Request.Form["userRole "];
//You can get the value of role
}
```

Comment: please look at the updated section, I do not need to have one hdnField in the controller, instead a model that has a field have to be filled with hdnField, model.Minprice=hdnValue

Answer (score 0):

The names of your inputs are incorrect. You should remove the `Model.` part from it. If you used `HtmlHelper.HiddenFor`, you'd get the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MaxPrice" value="@Model.MaxPrice" id="MaxPrice" />
```

This way, the inputs will get submitted to your model correctly.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866720/1765877).

Comment: it does not work, I do not know whats the problem, I have other field as you can see in my model that they work , but this hidden...

Comment: I also had used this : @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MinPrice, new { id = "MinPrice", Value = @Model.MinPrice })  , but it again des not fill MinPrice with the hdnValue,

Comment: That is really strange.. Are you sure the values Are updating correctly, before you submit the form?

Comment: Please see my comments tomorrow, I will update my post what happen exactly , thanks again

Comment: please kindly have a glance on my update, I am really fed up wit testing various approach

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after several test I found the solution sending values via ajax but building the data for the request in a string JSON format, where the hidden fields, are written without single quotes and the other fields with single quotes. Below is shown the example. I hope that this variant help you.

JavaScript code to send data to controller

```
            $("#saveSearchModel").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Variables for fields values
                var devision = $("#Devision").val();
                var gender = $("#Gender").val();
                var minPrice = $("#MinPrice").val();
                var maxPrice = $("#MaxPrice").val();
                var brand = $("#Brand").val();
                /*
                   Get the other fields...
                */
                // Data for pass to controller via ajax
                var data1 = "{'Devision':'" + devision + "','Gender':'" + gender + "',MinPrice:" + minPrice + ",MaxPrice:" + maxPrice + ",'Brand':'" + brand + /*Add the other fields...*/ + "'}";

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Controller/Action1',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: data1,
                    success: function (result) {
                        // Do something
                    }
                });
            });
```

Code in controller to receive data

```
            [HttpPost]
            public void Action1(SearchModel model)
            {
                // Gets the values of model
                string devision = model.Devision;
                string gender = model.Gender;
                int? minPrice = model.MinPrice;
                int? maxPrice = model.MaxPrice;
                string brand = model.Brand;
                /*
                    Gets the others values of model...
                */
            }
```